# Best way to update this data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of items that has its own separate row on a table and it has an Id that maps to another table. This is grabbing every item one at a time.

```
        List<Item> itemsFromRepo = new List<Item>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            itemsFromRepo.Add(_itemRepository.Get(item.ItemId));
        }
```

Is there a better more efficient way to query a database for these items than one at a time?

Comment: Your repository implementation has a `GetAll` method? Can you pass an expression to filter? Please, share the method in case you have it

Comment: As octavioccl suggests you should be able to fetch all the items at once instead of the inefficient Get on each. Without seeing your models and repository and assuming you want a collection of items from the database that match your items list, something like `var itemsFromRepo = context.Items.Where(i => items.Contains(i.ItemId)).ToList();` should be possible. Replace `context.Items` with an iqueryable like `_itemRepository.GetAll()` or `_itemRepository.Select()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing so I'm going to recap my understanding of your question and then respond to it with a possible solution based on that understanding. My understanding of your question is that you have a list of items already enumerated and you want to get results based on an ID property from your enumerated list. It looks like you want to get the results from a repository. One question to consider, are you enumerating the list just to get the results from the second table or do you need the results from the both tables? If you only need results from the last table in the query we can make things even more efficient but I'll assume you need both for now. Here's how I would get the data you're trying to get without the foreach loop:

## 1 Grab the criteria you need.

```
 var ids = items.Select(x => x.ItemId).Distinct().ToList();
```

## 2 Build a repository method to get data by a list of Ids.

```
//Assuming you're using Ints as your ID here, just sub in whatever ID you're using
            public static List<Item> GetByIDs(List<Int32> ids)
           {
               using(var dbContext = new YourDBContextHere())
               {
                 return dbContext.Items.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ItemId)).ToList();
               }
           }
```

Another thing to consider, depending on what you're doing you can batch your calls to make them significantly faster (You can potentially get your 'items' and your 'itemsFromRepo' at the same time and save a DB call).

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing and works great. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, out of curiosity how would you batch the call to get both list back at the same time?

Comment: There's a few options you have for returning everything in one call. The first is Entity Framework's built in 'Include ' functionality which allows you to return the related items in a single query e.g. 
dbContext.items.Include(x => x.Items)
This assumes you have FK relationships, you would probably want to map the result to a custom data transfer object. The related entites fetched with Include are brought back as a collection (a list if I recall correctly) so in order to access them you need to iterate over the collection.

Comment: Another option assuming you don't have a massive amount of data being returned is a great (and free) library called Entity Framework Plus. I've used this library at work to get some pretty significant performance gains on some fairly large queries. EF Plus allows you to write queries like this:
var itemsFuture = dbContext.items.Future();
var ItemsFuture = dbContext.Items.Future();
var items = itemsFuture.ToList();
Future allows you to batch multiple queries and send them off at the same time, as soon as you call ToList on a future future IQueryable it enumerates all other results.

Comment: Sorry for formatting on that, I'm new here and don't know how to format code in comments. See this link for more on EF Plus: http://entityframework-plus.net/tutorial-query#query-future

Answer (score -1):

You can select all the data you need to an array and work with it on the server-side, it will be faster

Answer (score -2):

put your data in a datatable and send that datatable

example

```
public DataTable CreateTable()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Label", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            return dt;
        } 
public postdata(formdata){
var myDataTable = CreateTable();
            foreach (var dataField in formData.PostedFields)
            {
                myDataTable.Rows.Add(dataField.Label, dataField.Value);
            }

 using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "WebFormTask";
               SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostedFields", myDataTable);
                               cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();
            }
}
```

Create a Store Procedure according to that.

Comment: The question is tagged entity framework. Why would anyone choose a datatable over a strongly typed POCO?

Comment: I think you've got the wrong question. It's about getting data from the database to code, not from code to the database.

Comment: Yeah, the question is phrased update but the code indicates it is a query. In either case I would craft an entity framework answer.